# New users asking questions to update old answers?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, new-users

So, upon writing this, I have found a similar meta question asking the a similar thing; ["Communicating with new users who ask a duplicate question"](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8285/communicating-with-new-users-who-ask-a-duplicate-question), to which the answer was to basically elaborate on the way the site works with dupe questions, etc.

In [this situation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/373040/73976) we have done that (I feel), but I don't think this really helps the new user. They have already found the dupe question, and have pointed out that the answer is apparently outdated. In that situation, the new user can't do anything about it, except ask a new question.

How should we deal with this - a new user (somewhat intentionally) asking a dupe question to update/bring attention to an outdated answer?

Comment: What situation is that?

Comment: Oh whoops, I forgot to add the link to the question haha

Comment: I'm not sure if the debate over "update existing answers" or "ask a new one" will be perfectly solved. On one hand, the answer is valid if you have an older version/patch of the game. On the other, people want answers for the current version of a game. It's sorta like like seeing the same questions for Python 2 vs. Python 3. In some cases, you really do want both questions and their answers separately. Yet, spreading out information makes it tougher to find. I'm not sure where the balance is for games, especially ones with multiple platforms and versions like Minecraft.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling dupes asking for updated info](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12611/handling-dupes-asking-for-updated-info)

Comment: Is **this** question a duplicate asking for updated info? Is that too meta for Meta?

Comment: No, it's not, because there's no reason to assume the policy on handling duplicates has changed since 2017. Even if it were, I believe this kind of question is still a duplicate, and therefore flagged it accordingly.